# Jquery Validator and fields that have been hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to get the [Jquery validationn plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) to not validate hidden fields on submission. For example, if we have HTML like this:

```
<div id="1">
  <input type="text" class="digits">
</div>
<div id="2">
  <input type="text" class="digits">
</div>
```

And then call:

```
$('div#2').hide();
```

and submit the form, even though the second input may have some wrong data inputted the form should still submit. I wanted to change the code of validate, but couldn't find the relevant fragments.

Comment: i believe the validation is done via setting classes on the elements? can you remove the class when you hide the element?

Comment: @Michel It does require me to specify the classes, but removing them seems like a bit of an ad-hoc solution. I want them to be validated if they appear again through `$('div#2').show();` and I would have to hardcode the classes into the code, or try to store them somewhere. I have a feeling it would be easier  to just make the validator skip over the hidden fields.

Comment: and you don't want to remove the class when hiding, and add the class when showing, i get your point. I'll search more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to remove validation from fields is to add `disabled` attribute to them.

```
var $div2 = $('div#2');
$div2.hide();

$('input, select, textarea', $div2).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

And they will not be validated. But this also causes disabled fields not to be submitted on server. If you do not need these manually hidden fields to be submitted on server, technique is good.

And another way is to manually add and remove all of the validation rules from the element, using [remove rules](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22remove.22rules) and [add rules](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules) functions. This is of course more complicated, as you will have to add and remove each rule one by one for each input.

Comment: I have a form with many elements appearing and disappearing based on what user selects before. When he chooses a certain thing from a dropdown menu I want a whole section fo the form to disappear, when he chooses a different one this section appears. I can't use hidden for that, cause these are all text input fields.